# Elemento Fieldset deve ser usado só em formulário?

Tags: html, html5, formulário, html-tags

O elemento `<fieldset>` só pode ser utilizado em formulários para sua organização e agrupamento de conteúdo ou posso utilizar em qualquer lugar do código?

Answer (score 3):

Existe o que funciona e o certo. Não dá erro usar fora de um formulário, mas não faz sentido usar fora.

Esta *tag* existe para dar uma semântica melhor ao que se está fazendo, inclusive atende aos requisitos de acessibilidade. Tem outras maneiras de agrupar elementos, mas essa diz que esses elementos são um grupo de campos e isto é importante para o seu SEO e tornar mais acessível.

Use para determinar algo que se refere a todos os campos do grupo. Além de estilizar que poderia ser feito com outra *tag* pode fazer ações específicas como desabilitar todos os campos deste grupo.

Se quer fazer certo só use dentro de um `<form>`.

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

Exemplo que funciona e não está em formulário (não faça isto em casa):

```css
fieldset {
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;    
}
```

```html
<div class>Título</div>
<fieldset>
Não usei em formulário
</fieldset>
```

Uso correto:

```css
fieldset {
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;    
}
```

```html
<form>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Endereço</legend>
      Tipo Logradouro: <input type = "text"><br/>
      Logradouro:<input type = "text"><br/>
      Número:<input type = "text">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Fieldset.js).

Answer (score 3):

Resumidamente não deve ser usado fora de um `form`, por uma questão de semântica! Presume-se que o `fieldset` é um conjunto de elementos que compõem parte ou um todo de um formulário. Usa-lo fora de um forme quebra a semântica sugerida pela W3C

> Muitas tecnologias assistivas usarão o elemento `<legend>` como se fosse parte da etiqueta de cada widget dentro do elemento `<fieldset>` correspondente. Por exemplo, alguns leitores de tela, como **Jaws** ou **NVDA**, pronunciarão o conteúdo da legenda antes de pronunciar o rótulo de cada widget.

O `fieldset` precisa de um elemento `legend` dentro. Isso pode ser ou não um problema para vc, mas para os leitores de tela a ausência dele com certeza vai ser um inconveniente...

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

Apesar que mesmo usando o `fieldset` fora de um `form` não haja problemas de validação do HTML, não é indicado, já que dentro dele deveriam haver `inputs`, e outros elementos de formulário. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**OBS:**

Caso queira agrupar elementos que não são de form vc pode usar `ul/li`, ou `tables`, ou `dl/dd`, ou `section/article` e por ai vai...